# Check result of printing with lp command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, cups

I'm ussing a linux (ubuntu 12), and want to print with `lp` command.

I'm following this [guide](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulp.htm)

I can print with this command:

```
lp -n 1 -o media=A3 -o sides=one-sided -o fitplot -d 8001 /path/file.pdf
```

But now need to check if the print is finished. How can do that? Thanks (note: `lpq` command only shows me spool empty...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpstat -p PRINTER` where PRINTER is the name of your printer (in your case, "8001" apparently) can tell you what job a printer is printing or whether it is idle.

Note that the information might not be always be exactly up-to-date. My printer happily tells me it's idle although it's still printing.

Comment: Im going to check this in my printer now. I hope it works.

Comment: Adding to this: you can only check if the printer finished the print, but that isn't an "fullOK" job status. You must manually check if the printer do the work as desired: not stapling, not folding, creasing, wrinkling or tearing the paper is not showed in that command. I didn't check if papper jams are showing there.